# Conflict between shape of (-1, 784) with input size of 200

Tags: python, pytorch

There is an error with the shape of a tensor and it's input size, as it is conflicting. I have absolutely no idea what to do at all. Because I am still new to this topic, which is the reason why you may or may not spot lines of code that are not needed at all. Just a heads up. If needed, personally contact me and I will send you the `.ipynb` file

If it matters I am doing computer vision, with the MNIST handrawn numbers dataset.

```
import torch
import torchvision
import numpy as np
import torch.nn as nn
import torch.nn.functional as F
from torchvision.datasets import MNIST
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from torch.utils.data import SubsetRandomSampler, DataLoader

dataset = MNIST(root='data/', download=True)

def split_indices(dataset, rate):
    eval = int(dataset*rate/100)
    index = np.random.permutation(dataset)
    return index[eval:], index[:eval]
 
train_index, eval_index = split_indices(len(dataset), rate=20)

dataset = MNIST(root='data/', train=True, transform=transforms.ToTensor())

train_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(train_index)
train_dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=200, sampler=train_sampler)

val_sampler = SubsetRandomSampler(eval_index)
val_dl = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=200, sampler=eval_sampler)
 
inputs = 28*28
nums = 10
model = nn.Linear(inputs, nums)
 
class MnistModel(nn.Module):
        def __init__(self):
            super().__init__()
            self.linear = nn.Linear(inputs, nums)

        def forward(self, xb):
            xb = xb.reshape(-1, 784)
            outputs = self.linear(xb)
            return outputs

        def accuracy(x, y):
            print(torch.sum(x == y).item()/len(x))

model = MnistModel()

for images, labels in train_dl:
        outputs = model(images)
        break

loss_fn = F.cross_entropy
loss = loss_fn(outputs, labels)
opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=7)

def loss_batch(model, loss_fn, xb, yb, opt=None, metric=None):
    preds = model(xb)
    loss = loss_fn(preds, yb)
 
    if opt is not None:
        loss.backward()
        opt.step()
        opt.zero_grad()
 
    metric_result = None
    if metric is not None:
        metric_result = metric(preds, yb)
 
    return loss.item(), len(xb), metric_result
 
def evaluate(model, loss_fn, valid_dl, metric=None):
    with torch.no_grad():
        results = [loss_batch(model, loss_fn, xb, yb, metric=metric) for xb, yb in valid_dl]
 
        losses, nums, metrics = zip(*results)
        total = np.sum(nums)
        avg_loss = np.sum(np.multiply(losses, nums)) / total
 
        avg_metric = None
        if metric is not None:
            avg_metric = np.sum(np.multiply(metrics, nums)) / total
 
        return avg_loss, total, avg_metric
 
def accuracy(outputs, labels):
    _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
    return torch.sum(preds == labels).item() / len(preds)

eval_loss, total, eval_acc = evaluate(model, loss_fn, val_dl, metric=accuracy)
print(f"loss: {eval_loss}, accuracy: {eval_acc*100}")

def fit(epochs, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl, valid_dl, metric=None):
    for epoch in range(epochs):
        for xb, yb in train_dl:
            loss,_,_ = loss_batch(model, xb, yb, opt)

        result = evaluate(model, loss_fn, valid_dl, metric)
        eval_loss, total, eval_metric = result

        if metric is None:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, loss: {loss.item()}")

        else:
            print(f"Epoch: {epoch+1}, loss: {loss.item()}, metric: {metric.__name__} {eval_metric}")

model = MnistModel()

opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=7)
fit(5, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl, eval_dl, accuracy) #Error line
```

Error output:

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)

<ipython-input-55-90c5585d3b40> in <module>()
      1 opt = torch.optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=7)
----> 2 fit(5, model, loss_fn, opt, train_dl, eval_dl, accuracy)

3 frames

<ipython-input-49-afd130f584e4> in forward(self, xb)
     18 
     19     def forward(self, xb):
---> 20         xb = xb.reshape(-1, 784)
     21         outputs = self.linear(xb)
     22         return outputs

RuntimeError: shape '[-1, 784]' is invalid for input of size 200
```

Comment: According to your definition of `loss_batch` the second argument should be `loss_fn` but you appear to be missing that argument in `loss,_,_ = loss_batch(model, xb, yb, opt)`

Comment: thanks that was able to fix it, I was too frustrated and I didn't look at the problem clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use reshape for torch.Tensor.

Use torch.nn.Flatten() to flatten your image.
This will look consistent in your program.